# Conductive glue

Tags: experimental-physics, semiconductor-physics, experimental-technology, cryogenics

I would like to use some conductive glue to contact a silicon chip's back gate. Any suggestions on what to use? Can I use thermal silver paste? I would be operating at cryogenic temperatures below 4K.

Comment: Many low-temperature applications I have been periphereally involved in also had radio-cleanliness requirements. Is that an issue here?

Comment: Yes, I would be measuring RF signals through other pins. The contact through the glue only needs to be DC.

Comment: Sorry. "radio-purity" was meant in terms of radioactivity. I've done low-background particle physics for the last eight years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used silver conductive paint for quick tests of superconductors in a helium cryostat, and it worked fine.

Will it also be a vacuum? I've seen others use a blob of indium solder for electrical connections as well.

Comment: Thanks. It will be in Vacuum. Any suggestions on which paint I could buy cheap at low quantities?

Comment: If it is high vaccuum, the indium solder may be a better option then, as the paint can outgas for awhile.  Assuming that is not a problem, I think we just used cheap silver conductive paint from the local hobby store.  However a quick search shows some specifically for vaccuum specimens -- http://www.tedpella.com/semmisc_html/SEMpaint.htm#anchor16040   There's plenty others out there.  I can't recommend a specific one as I don't remember brands or anything.  It probably doesn't matter.